# Why do I get a "no route" error when remotely posting vs remotely updating a post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

Some background: I have a Posts controller which is used for users to create or update posts. In a post form, a user starts writing their post. This post can either be saved as a draft (and then the form switches functionality to submit to the "update" action of the controller) and later be posted to a page, or be directly posted to a page.

These forms post remotely to a page, which appends a table with the post inside.

Currently, I have a problem: submitting a form breaks down because, in appending the table, I get an error "ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"vote", :controller=>"posts", :post_id=>245, :positive=>true})". This refers to a line of code in the posts view:

```
 <%= link_to (image_tag("icons/upvote.png", :height => "15px")), vote_post_path(:post_id => post.id, :positive => true), :remote => true %>
```

I should mention that appending the post to the table is done by using an @post variable that remains available from the controller.

NOW the weird thing is that this error ONLY occurs when a post has been submitted directly to the "create" action, and trying to append the table with the post. When a saved draft is submitted to the "update" action and appended onto the table, this doesn't occur.

Does anyone have any advice as to why this is? I can provide more code where relevant.

EDIT: the relevant section of my routes file:

```
 resources :posts do
   member do
     get :vote
   end
 end
```

Comment: can you post your routes file

Comment: hey i added the relevant section of my routes file, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you have the "vote" action as a member action, not a collection action. Switch it to:

```
 resources :posts do

   collection do
      get :vote 

   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what happens:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :votes 
end
```

Comment: hi, thanks again for your responses. This breaks to the error showing up for all posts partials, even for saved ones. Any idea why?